# Question about derived functors

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $F,G, H: Mod \to Mod$ be three left exact functors such that $R^iF(-)\cong R^iG(-)$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. We consider the exact sequence
$$\cdots\to R^iF(M)\to R^iG(M)\to R^iH(M)\to R^{i+1}F(M)\to R^{i+1}G(M)\to R^{i+1}H(M)\to\cdots$$
where $M$ is an $R$-module ($R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring).

From the above exact sequence, can we have $R^iH(M)=0$?

Comment: Where exactly does your exact sequence come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derived functors don't matter in this case. You just have an exact sequence:

$$
\dots \longrightarrow A \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} C \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} D \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} E \longrightarrow \dots
$$

in which $f$ and $i$ are isomorphisms.

But this means that morphisms $g$ and $h$ are zero:

$$
B = \mathrm{im}\ f = \mathrm{ker}\ g \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad g = 0
$$

and

$$
\mathrm{im}\ h = \mathrm{ker}\ i = 0 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad h = 0
$$

So, your exact sequence at $C$ is just

$$
0 \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0 \ .
$$

Hence

$$
C = 0 \ .
$$

So, indeed

$$
R^iH(M) = 0 .
$$